# Facebook API not working sometime for some URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting number of shares and comment of blog posts using facebook graph api for my blog, but sometimes it do not return shares and comment.

Following URL is not giving number of share and comments.

http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.lehedonist.com/jeans-is-the-new-whiskey-2001

BUT it is working for this URL:

Example: http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.lehedonist.com/spring-slam-fashion-war-ss16-1965

Comment: Is it safe to assume if those fields do not exist, there are 0 shares/comments?

Comment: It was displaying share and comments for those URL before but suddenly its not showing.

Comment: If it was showing `"shares" : 0, "comments": 0` before, then I suspect that would be a Facebook API change. If I go to that site and use an article with no comments, but some shares, it does give the shares field, but no comments field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow wonder why it's even working to request these URLs without an access token to be honest.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/url

It only gives a result if there no version info in the URL. To do this in the v2.5 way properly, you'd have to use

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/?access_token={access_token}&fields=id,og_object,share&id=http://www.lehedonist.com/spring-slam-fashion-war-ss16-1965
```

where `{access_token}` is an actual access token.

Results will look like

```
{
    "id": "http://www.lehedonist.com/spring-slam-fashion-war-ss16-1965",
    "og_object": {
        "id": "987675524635070",
        "description": "Not your usual fashion post, we decode styles best suited to your personality and what should you be sporting next summer",
        "title": "Spring Summer 16 fashion: The clash of fashion personalities",
        "type": "article",
        "updated_time": "2015-10-08T11:24:32+0000",
        "url": "http://www.lehedonist.com/spring-slam-fashion-war-ss16-1965"
    },
    "share": {
        "comment_count": 2,
        "share_count": 81
    }
}
```

Comment: you're life saver, just one more question, How to generate access token ?

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: 

**Unknown fields: og_object.**

Comment: You get the error when doing what? Please give more details. Have you added the `v2.5/` to the reuest path?

Comment: YESSS! It works. Thank you so much.

I generated access token using my fb profile, is it safe to use my access token on my client site ?

Comment: You need to create an app and subsequently an app access token. That's why I've linked the according docs